# Grow animation with Teechart on Android

Tags: java, android, teechart

I am trying to use simple grow/shrink animation using Teecharts on Android. I cant find any tutorial or documentation on it, so I came up with the following code:

```
    SeriesAnimation seriesAnimation = new SeriesAnimation();
    seriesAnimation.setActive(true);
    seriesAnimation.setStartAtMin(false);
    seriesAnimation.setSteps(500);
    seriesAnimation.setStartValue(0);
    Series series = Series.createNewSeries(chart.getChart(), Bar3D.class, null);
    series.add(new DateTime(System.currentTimeMillis()), 33);
    series.add(new DateTime(System.currentTimeMillis() - 10000000), 433);
    seriesAnimation.setSeries(series);

    chart.getTools().add(seriesAnimation);

    chart.addSeries(series);
    try {
        seriesAnimation.execute();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

But there is no effect at all on the chart. Anyone has any pointer to at least the very basic use of animation for Android version of Teecharts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answered in the Steema support forums, [here](http://www.teechart.net/support/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=13680&p=59953#p59953)